# How can I decrypt a string in ColdFusion with a key generated from a remote source?

Tags: web-services, authentication, encryption, coldfusion

I am working on a User Authentication mechanism for ColdFusion Web Service called from mobile apps. The app developer wants to encrypt the User Id and password using AES. ColdFusion requires a `key` in order for the string to be decrypted, but, how can I know the key, if it's not generated on my server?

Comment: ask your app dev for the key? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, @Henry has it right. You will need the key (stored securely of course).